Is there any way to integrate the new .NET 8 Identity API endpoints with the Microsoft Identity Platform (Azure AD B2C)?
I have recently been spending some time learning the new Identity endpoints that have been added to ASP.NET Core Web APIs as part of .NET 8. I am currently trying to develop a .NET MAUI application that will have logins for specific customers that we create for them and they can then use to sign into the application. To secure this login functionality, we have been looking at making use of the Microsoft Identity Platform in Azure (particularly Azure AD B2C) and integrating this with a web API which the MAUI application will consume for authentication and authorization.
I like how easy it is to setup these new endpoints however I can't find a way to configure these API endpoints at all with the Microsoft Identity Platform and all of the documentation seems to involve saving all the login information in a database. Is this a possibility yet or am I going about this the wrong way? I don't have that much experience yet on the mobile app and web API side of things as most of my prior experience has been with developing MVC web applications.

You can use the Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) to start an authentication workflow with your Azure AD B2C tenant. The process for integrating the Azure AD B2C identity management service into a mobile application is as follows:

Create an Azure Active Directory B2C tenant.
Register your mobile application with the Azure Active Directory B2C tenant.
Create policies for sign-up and sign-in, and forgot password user flows.
Use the Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) to start an authentication workflow with your Azure Active Directory B2C tenant.


Authenticate Users with Azure Active Directory B2C - Xamarin | Microsoft Learn
Zero Trust for Identity integration overview | Microsoft Learn
